# Is there any way to encrypt the Http basic authentication password in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, http-authentication

I have written the following in my controller:

```
http_basic_authenticate_with name: "foo", password: "bar", except: [:new, :show, :edit, :create]
```

but when I push it to my repo, the password is there for everyone to see. Is there any way to encrypt the password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use environment-variables for this :)
There's a gem (Like for everything basically): https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv

In your .env file you'd have the following:

```
AUTHENTICATION_USERNAME="foo"
AUTHENTICATION_PASSWORD="bar"
```

Where as in your controller you write it like so:

```
http_basic_authenticate_with name: ENV['AUTHENTICATION_USERNAME'], password: ENV['AUTHENTICATION_PASSWORD'], except: [:new, :show, :edit, :create]
```

This way your code is completely separated from the actual information.
Make sure to not add the .env-file to your git-repository by adding this to your gitignore:

```
.env
```

---

So what this does is it'll load these variables you set up in `.env` into your existing environment variables. This way somebody needs to actually log into your server and get access to that particular file in order to get the username/password. And this should be more secure than having the username/password in plain text inside your controller ;)

Comment: Thanks for the very comprehensive answer. Excuse my ignorance, but what is a .env file and how do I get it/ifnd it? I have installed the gem but can not locate that file anywhere

Comment: Hi. You will have to create this file in your home directory. `touch ~/.env` does the job. The .env file will eventually get added to your other environment variables your system already has. This way the application can use them.